# DateTime shows a different value when editing a node

Tags: nodes, datetime, feeds

I am using Feeds to import field data into nodes.

For a Date field, I am using "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" as the format for importing.

[image]

When viewing the node, it shows the correct imported date.

[image]

However, when editing the newly imported node, the Date is correct but the time changes.

With the field setting set to change the time to the user's timezone, the following shows in the field.

[image]

I tried changing the field settings to have no time zone conversion, but the following was shown instead.

[image]

What can be done to make the time show correctly when modifying the node?

Comment: What version of Drupal?  It may matter here.

Comment: I had an issue with date rounding off to the nearest 15 minutes once.  Looks like that's what's happening here, can't remember if or how I fixed it though.

Comment: @Darvanen Thank you, that was actually exactly it! Advanced settings on the field was changed to 1 minute from 15min. Thank you!